# “missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed” Error in if statement in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write an if statement, that translates into the following:

"If an individual's Honesty_Humility score is greater than or equal to the median Honesty_Humility score, print ('H'). If an individual's Honesty_Humility score is less than the median Honesty_Humility score, print ('L'). Since some individuals' Honesty_Humility score is missing, I want to add that if that is the case, then print ('NA')"

The code I came up with so far is the following:

```
for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
    dataTest$hhScore[[i]] <-
        if (Hon_Hum$Honesty_Humility[[i]] >=median(Hon_Hum$Honesty_Humility, na.rm = TRUE)){
            print ('H')
        } else if (Hon_Hum$Honesty_Humility[[i]] < median(Hon_Hum$Honesty_Humility, na.rm = TRUE)){
     print('L')
    } else {
      print('NA')
    }

}
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Error in if (Hon_Hum$Honesty_Humility[[i]] >= median(Hon_Hum$Honesty_Humility,  :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Apparently, `Hon_Hum$Honesty_Humility` contains `NA` values. A comparison between an `NA` value and a number returns `NA`. And `if` can't deal with `NA` in its condition.

Comment: Yes that's right... there are NA values, so how can i overcome this? I would like the if statement to return 'NA' for NA values

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making this a reproducible example

Comment: Test for `NA` first: `if(is.na(...)) print("NA") else ...`

Comment: That worked, thank you